# Is there any way of getting rid of the "bbPress Forums" text on the forum index page of my wordpress site after installing bbPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am using the OceanWP wordpress theme and I recently installed the bbPress forum plugin onto my site. It is working fine but the only problem is that on my Forum Index page, underneath the header, there is some text which has appeared which says "bbPress forums" which I didn't want.

http://prntscr.com/q9lik2

I was just wondering if there was any way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

this text comes from the custom post type description. it can be hidden with this filter :

```
add_filter("get_the_post_type_description", function ($description, $post_type_obj) {

    if ("forum" === $post_type_obj->name) {
        $description = NULL;
    }

    return $description;

}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: Hi @Kaperto, thank you very much for this! I'm a little unsure where to put this code, though, I pasted it in the functions.php file but it caused an error on my site. Was that the correct file to put it in?

Comment: yes this can be put in functions.php. what error do you have ?

Comment: ahhh, thanks. I was getting a critical error when refreshing my page but I realised that was because I put a "}" at the end of the code before pasting the code above. After removing the "}" there is no longer an error but the code does not save. When I click "update file" the loading circle just keeps spinning and doesn't save or update.

I think it may be because I am not closing the code in front of it properly:
http://prntscr.com/qaw11e

Answer (score 0):

I've installed OceanWP and bbPress on my localhost and couldn't find option to hide forums description, so I would recommend hiding it using CSS for now. Add this css code to Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS

```
.forum-archive .page-subheading { display: none; }
```

Comment: thank you so much for looking into this:) this code works perfectly. I was just wondering as you said, i can use this solution for now, is there any reason it shouldn't be used as a permanent fix?

Comment: Actually it's not perfect solution as the subheading is still there but hidden from the user, this may affect SEO. this is just a small workaround but I'm sure there's better solutions :) However, if you like the answer, please vote.